# Check if ALT key is pressed

Tags: c, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

After testing a lot I can't record if Alt key is pressed using **GetAsyncKeyState** in a C program.
When I try this:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT))
    // do something
```

It works properly, but when I try this

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU))
    // do something
```

It doesn't work. 
So my question is "How I can record ALT?".

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is not working ? Program crash ? Program doesn't build ? Section after 'if' is never called ? What are you testing ? Pressing Alt key alone or in combination with another character ?

Comment: Can you explain why 'roy' is the best answer ? Reading following Microsoft Web page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes you can immediately see that VK_MENU = 0x12 = 18 !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the code below to find out the value of any key that perfectly fits in  `GetAsyncKeyState` , I think it is 18 for `ALT` key .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#if       _WIN32_WINNT < 0x0500
#undef  _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT   0x0500
#endif
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    char i;
    for(i=8; i<190; i++)
    {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(i)== -32767)
        {
            cout<<int (i)<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```